# insert into query showing syntax error

Tags: sql

```
sql = "insert into Attendance (Student ID, Department, Semester) 
        values (" & lblsid.Caption & ",'" & cmbsrdept.Text & "'," & cmbsrsem.Text & ")"


db.Execute (sql)
```

why this is showing syntax error in insert into statement

Comment: Can you please provide the error being shown?

Comment: What is the language of the app? What is the db engine? Could you please copy the error message?

Comment: you are missing single quotes around text values

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful I suppose it is ASP.

Comment: no no it is vb 6.0 ...have written sql queries into it

Comment: it is microsoft jet 4.0 oledb provider

Comment: Could you show the exact error  ..

Comment: "syntax error in INSERT INTO"

Comment: run the code in debug mode and then try to execute the querynalone.

Comment: run the code in debug mode and then try to execute the querynalone.